# Use jQuery to detect which font Browser selected

Tags: jquery, css

The `font-family` attribute in CSS accepts lists of font names to provide backup options in case the user does not have the 1st, 2nd, etc. font on their computer. Is there a way using jQuery to detect which of the fonts listed the browser is using?

For example if my CSS is:

```
body {
    font-family: 'SuperCoolFont', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Arial', 'Comic Sans MS';
}
```

I want to know which option the browser settled on. If the user didn't have the first 3 options I want the resulting answer to be `'Arial'`. Is this possible with jQuery?

A simple test of `$('body').css('font-family');` returns the whole list of fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little complicated to do.

[DetectFont](https://github.com/Wildhoney/DetectFont) accepts an element to check and uses `getComputedStyle` to get a list of the fonts. It compares the widths of the fonts in `getComputedStyle` using `canvas` and the `measureText` method to figure out which one is actually being rendered on the client.

Comment: OK. Sounds like using `canvas` may be the only way to do this. Not what I was hoping to hear, but it works.